# Google Test - unreferenced local variable

Tags: c++, testing, visual-studio-2008, googletest

I am testing some code with Google Test. And one of my function is return a `std::logic_error` exception. I wanted to write a test where I am expecting that this error will be thrown. I am testing with google test und using Visual Studio 2008:

```
TEST(submatrix, matrix_too_small)
{
    // an instance of a matrix class
    matrix A(1, 2);

    // a second instance of a matrix class
    matrix subA(1, 1);
    // generating this form of a submatrix should throw an error
    EXPECT_THROW(matrix_func::submatrix(A, subA, 1, 1), std::logic_error);
}
```

My question is: Why does Visual Studio 2008 give me here a warning: **Warning C4101: 'exc': Unreferenced local variable**?

Comment: Could you show a code on the line for which the warning is given?

Comment: That's curious. The macro definitions do not seem to contain a variable named `exc`. Any chance that you do not use the official versions, or an outdated version of Google Test?

Comment: @nikitoz: The line is shows to the line where EXPECT_THROW is written.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: That may be the point. I am using version 1.6.1...

Comment: @starki: Where did you get a version 1.6.1? I cannot find it on code.google.com, there is nothing between 1.6.0 and 1.7.0-rc1...

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I am sorry. I mean 1.6

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-E`, or whatever Visual Studio option will show you the output of the preprocessor?